# A templated function that receives std::pair as an argument and deduces the types from braced-list initialization

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, list-initialization

I'm trying to create a templated function that receives an std::pair and I want the types to be
deduced implicitly without specifying them when I call the function with braced list initialization. I've tried the following code but it doesn't compile (I'm using visual studio 2017).
I'd love some help making this work.
Thanks.

```
template <typename Key, typename Value>
void foo(std::pair<Key, Value> arg)
{}

int main()
{
    foo({1.0, "some string"}); // doesn't compile
    foo(std::pair{ 1.0, "some string" }); // compiles when I specify the type this way
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initializer lists induce a so-called "non-deduced context", they don't play well with template argument deduction. You can instead provide an additional overload

```
template <typename Key, typename Value>
void foo(Key&& k, Value&& v)
{
   foo(std::make_pair(std::forward<Key>(k), std::forward<Value>(v)));
}
```

which simply forwards the call to your original function template and which can be invoked via

```
foo(1.0, "some string");
```

Note that the call syntax omits the braces. You can of course put the original `foo` implementation right into the body of this new function template, if you prefer to have only one template.